# Does the new iPad support Core Bluetooth, or is this limited to the iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a small question about the Core Bluetooth framework. I know Core Bluetooth only works with iOS 5.0 or greater, but the Apple documentation also says it only works on the iPhone 4S.

Does it work with the new iPad as well, or just the iPhone 4S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new iPad [supports Bluetooth 4.0](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), including [the Low Energy feature](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/elijahparker/timelapse-powerful-features-brilliant-timelapse/posts/186436) required by Core Bluetooth. I think it would be safe to assume all iOS devices newer than the iPhone 4S will have this support going forward.

Odds are, the documentation has not yet been updated for this device.

Comment: Hi Brad, Thank you for your quick response. Are you confirm the iPad 3 supports Core Bluetooth functionality? Because I am trying to buy a ipad 3 for testing my app which communicate Bluetooth hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a BLE app and I can confirm 100% that the new iPad (iPad 3) works with BLE and therefore the coreBluetooth framework.

Comment: Thanks for ur info Kj, am waiting for this answer. small clarification     If I installed my app with CB framework on one ipad3, is there a possible to test this app infront of another ipad3 so that my first ipad display the name of the device by using peripheral.name attribute?

Comment: Quick question, can the iPhone 4S be paired with an iPad 3 BLE?

Comment: I don't think so because the 4S and iPad 3 don't broadcast a BLE signal, they only receive it.

Comment: This might change with iOS 6 …

Comment: @kj13ennett ***I don't think so because the 4S and iPad 3 don't broadcast a BLE signal*** well, that means an iphone (using BLE mode) cannot pair/communicate with another iphone. It can only be used to communicate with other non apple hardware which support BLE. That is strange